# Does this function have global maxima?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm wondering if, for example, $\sin(\sqrt{3}+x^2+y)$ (also for $\cos(x,y)$) or whatever the input is,  the global maxima exists? Wolfram says it has no global maxima only local.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the question as you posed it to Wolfram?  I find it hard to believe that Wolfram (Alpha?) would not recognize $1$ as the largest value attained by the function(s) you describe. (The standard definition of global maximum allows for the maximum value to be attained multiple times. Does Wolfram think a global maximum must be *strictly* larger than the value at every other point?)

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=max+sin(%5Csqrt(3)%2Bx%5E2%2By)

Comment: Huh! Wow, thanks. I wonder how WA arrived at the particular values for $x$ and $y$ that it did for its local maximum.

Answer (score 1):

It has infinitely many global maxima. One way of see this is, as $\sin(\cdot)$ is a periodic function, and $f(x,y) = x^2 + y + \sqrt{3}$ lies in $ (- \infty , \infty)$ which implies the function $\sin( x^2 + y + \sqrt{3})$ would take the same value over and over again.

Another way of showing this is by analytical method:

Let $$ f(x,y) = \sin(\sqrt{3} + x^2 + y)$$
$\partial_x f(x,y) = 2x \cos  (\sqrt{3} + x^2 + y) $ and $ \partial_y f(x,y) =  \cos  (\sqrt{3} + x^2 + y) $

$ \Rightarrow $ A point $(x,y)$ can be termed as critical point if $ \sqrt{3} + x^2 + y = \cfrac{n \pi}{2} $ and $x =0$ or $x \ne 0$

For the first case $ y = \cfrac{n \pi}{2} - \sqrt{3}$, which on placing in $f(x,y)$ gives $ \pm 1$, as here $n \in \mathbf I$ , in this case, there would more than one point where $f(x,y) = 1$

For the second case $y = \cfrac{n \pi}{2} - \sqrt{3}$, which on placing in $f(x,y) = sin(x^2)$ which is just a periodic function, hence there would be infinitely many global maxima.

Note: All extrema are critical points.

Comment: Can you state and/or link to the definition of global maximum you are using? The standard definition allows for the maximum value to be attained at multiple points.

Comment: Oh, I relied on the thought that they must be one unique maxima, but As you pointed out and I've verified the same, for this function, they are infinite maximas. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin(\sqrt3+x^2+y)\leq1.$$
The equality occurs for $x=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ and $y=-\sqrt3,$ which says that $1$ is a maximal value.